# Efficiently removing an item from Java LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

Here is the pseudo-code I am using to remove an item from the linked-list:

```
public static void removeByID(LinkedList<Fruit> fruits, int fruitID) {
    for(Fruit f : fruits) {
      if (f.ID == fruitID) {
         fruits.remove(f);
         return;
      }
    }
}
```

I am thinking this is not very efficient as `fruits.remove()` will once again iterate over the list. Wondering if there is a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I expected this code to throw [ConcurrentModificationException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html) because LinkedList is modified during iteration. Just fired up eclipse and no such exception was ever thrown. What am I missing?

Comment: @Gowtham the reason why it isn't doing that is the `return`: `fruits.remove()` just marks the collection as modified, the next operation on the (hidden) iterator would - if there was one - see that and throw.

Comment: @zapl Thanks. That makes it clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a `java.util.LinkedList`, use the Iterator.

```
Iterator<Fruit> it = fruits.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()) {
    if(it.next().ID == fruitID) {
        it.remove();
        break;
    }
}
```

This will result in only a single traversal. The Iterator returned has access to the underlying link structure and can perform a removal without iterating.

The Iterator is implicitly used anyway when you use the for-each loop form. You'd just be retaining the reference to it so you can make use of its functionality.

You may also use [`listIterator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#listIterator-int-) for O(n) insertions.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, not in terms of asymptotic complexity. That's the price you pay for using a `LinkedList`: removals require a traversal over the list. If you want something more efficient, you need to use a different data structure.

You're in fact doing two traversals here if you've got a singly linked list: the `.remove()` call needs to find the parent of the given node, which it can't do without another traversal.

Comment: @FabioCardoso That also requires a traversal of the list (inside the `indexOf()` call).

Comment: Have a look at LinkedHashMap if you need predictable iteration order. You should get a (almost) constant time remove

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access elements from a collection that have a unique attribute, it is better to use a HashMap instead, with that attribute as key.

```
Map<Integer, Fruit> fruits = new HashMap<Integer, Fruit>();
// ...
Fruit f = fruits.remove(fruitID);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the above linked lists generally need traversal for any operation. Avoiding multiple traversal can probably be done with an iterator. Although, if you are able to relate fruit to fruit.ID ahead of time you may be able to speed up your operations because you can a void the slow iterative look up. This will still require a different data structure, namely a Map (Hashmap probably).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your post, using a HashMap appears to a good solution.
In addition, if we suppose that you need also to search a fruit using the fruitID into your set, HashMap will make the search time barely constant.

Regarding complexity, you can find additional information on [Simple Notions article](http://simplenotions.wordpress.com/2009/05/13/java-standard-data-structures-big-o-notation/) depending the data structure that you use.